# autocomplete disable in joomla administrartor

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to disable autocomplete login details when i am click on administrator login.[image: stop this prediction]

I tried autocomplete ="off",oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" but nothing work. I know it's a browser property but i need to do this clear website audit. i seen this kind of validation on payment gateway.

Comment: Try using `autocomplete="nope"`

Comment: Ha!  I thought you were being snarky.  (rather out of character for a moderator)  Then I checked it out and that's legitimate advice.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion  This StackOverflow page is so bloated with redundant answers, that it uses pagination: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/2943403

Comment: We kinda havta close this one as not a Joomla question, right?  I assume that is why Lodder didn't post an answer.

Comment: autocomplete="nope" is not working for me in Chrome, if the input field name is "username".

Comment: But it's really not a Joomla question basically...

Comment: this is a joomla question. I am facing issues that's why i am asking to you. it's not for fun.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: Short version : it is not really auto-complete reducing security, it is browsers password manager trying to improve it, so disabling auto-complete does not work. Stopping it requires making it so the browser does not recognize it as a login. The best solution would probably be a custom login using a text field without autocomplete, but I think that most available extensions make a point of working with passwords managers. And the reason I am writing this that there is a good reason for that, you generally do want to support password management since in practice alternatives are even worse.

Comment: If you are validating to something specific you might want to search/ask based on that. There might be ready solutions or answers for that specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

Despite it is not a Joomla question, it is still could be a relevant question in many area in Joomla Forms too and can be applied in Joomla, so I try to give a useful working solution (which I've found among a lot of nonworking and old solutions).

**So the login form:** (should be renamed according to your needs)

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    <input class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="text">              
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="demo-submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>  
</form>
```

**The useful javascript code:** (to include)

```
<script src="https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/assets/js/jquery.disableAutoFill.min.js"></script>
```

**And the jQuery script:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var $ = jQuery;

$('#login-form').disableAutoFill({
    passwordField: '.password',
    debugMode: false,
    randomizeInputName: true,
    callback: function() {
    return checkForm();
    }
});

function checkForm() {
    form = document.getElementById('login-form');

    if (form.password.value == '') {
        alert('Cannot leave Password field blank.');
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (form.username.value == '') {
        alert('Cannot leave User Id field blank.');
        form.username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

I tried this and it works even in Chrome where most of the times this autocomplete avoiding solutions fail. I did not try it on all browsers but the author claims it works on all browsers.
The source with all of the info about this is here:
https://github.com/terrylinooo/jquery.disableAutoFill

I hope this can help.

**UPDATE** - **CUSTOMIZED SOLUTION FOR JOOMLA ADMIN LOGIN**

Now, the above code works on many forms but not on Joomla admin login. I knew that I will have to take my time to customize the solution on this question to make it a Joomla question. So here is how to disable autofill/autocomplete on the Joomla Admin Login page:

**it's relatively simple at the end.**

I worked on the template: **administrator/modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php**

(create a backup copy of this file to somewhere before edit that, then if you screw up something you can just place back that original file in place) Or, actually the right way is **to create a template override of this module default.php** file in the template manager of the admin.

**1.** **On the top of the file after** the closing php tag ( ?> ) paste the jquery import, just this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2.** In the username and password input fields, add an attribute (autocomplete="off") (it may sound stupid but it should be there)

**3.** At the password input field change the type attribute to text ( type= "text" )

**4.** Then, place the following javascript/jQuery code at the end of the file (after the closing tag of the form `**</form>**`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#mod-login-username').attr({
            'name' : 'mygod',
            'type' : 'text',
            // 'readonly' : true,
        });
        $('#mod-login-password').attr({
            'name' : 'mygod2',
            'type' : 'text',
            // 'readonly' : true,
        });
    });


    $('#form-login').on('submit', function(){
            $('#mod-login-username').attr('name','username');
            $('#mod-login-password').attr('name','passwd');
            $('#mod-login-password').attr('type','password');
    });    

</script>
```

And that's it, it worked for me without a problem and I could signed in to my admin without problem, autofill was not ignited in the browser (I tried this on Chrome and on Firefox). I hope that it will work for you too and you can confirm this for me at your side. (it still could be simplified a lot, but at least it works now).

And just showing the result visually:

[image]

Firefox - Autocomplete is not ignited and the Joomla authentication works too. It's the same in Chrome.

Comment: I tried this but not worked at all... I changed the input type from password to text. prediction is stopped as well as save password alert. But password showing in text form. i used css to show text to disc form.  <style>
       #txtPassword{
           -webkit-text-security:disc;
       }
   </style> . But it's not work in firefox. Please help

Comment: @mohan I updated my answer with the working solution(codes) on this question

Comment: thanks @Zollie sir.. It's working. but now another problem arrived that now saved password alert is active again. Can You help on this...?

Comment: @mohan -- I've checked this a bit further and I also turned on auto save password on my browsers and it is still not popping up when I am submitting my admin credentials when the above code is in my module default.php. So I really do not understand now why it is popping up for you... Are you sure that you precisely follow the steps what I gave above? Thanks.

Comment: sorry sir... It's working on administrator login page. Suggest same functionality for Edit account(User edit page). Input code is coming from XML file. and jquery will not work in XML

Comment: @mohan -- No problem. The original question was about Joomla admin login. Now the new question is about Editor user login (I think you want it on front-end login). You should close this question and should open a new question on this. That's the way it should work here. As I'll have a bit of more time I'll formulate a solution (answer) on that new question too.

Comment: it's not frontend. after login any user can edit their details in which user have password change option. I am asking for that opton.

Comment: @mohan - OK, it is clearer now. Please if you could open a new question about that and you can link back this question too in that new question. Your original question here is answered and can be closed.