# How can you hide Joomla admin password while inputting the characters?

Tags: administrator, login, joomla-3.9, account-password

I have followed the advice at [autocomplete disable in joomla administrator](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23686/autocomplete-disable-in-joomla-administrartor).

How can I hide the password characters while I am typing without losing the functionality provided by [Zollie](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/12524/zollie)?

Comment: By default, a browser will show small circles that represent each character entered. Are you saying you want to hide those small circles?

Comment: You are right that is the default functionality, but if you follow the  forum link on the original post on the joomla solution the password is viewable and not hidden with small circles

Comment: Ah so you would like to disable autocomplete but still mask the password?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution will be to create a custom font (this tutorial explain a way to do this https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Font) with small circles for all characters and bind this font to your password text input.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myCustomFont;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('pathToYourCustomFont.otf');
}
#mod-login-password
{
      font-family: "myCustomFont";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution really solves the issue.